# Yahoo Boss API (version 1) shut down for good?

Tags: yahoo-boss-api

It looks like the Yahoo Boss API terms of service has recently changed to an exclusive [pay as you go model](http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/search/bosspricing/details.html) and that the "**Key Terms ? Query Suggestions**" has been discontinued altogether according to this [Boss V2 Features Matrix](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/)

Can someone confirm that the original V1 server is shut down and there is no more access to the v1 server's "Key Terms ? Query Suggestions"?

I'm asking because my key terms query is not returning data as of today. I've got a search query and API on the original Boss network that, prior to today returned related keywords for a given input string. Today, it does not answer.

Update: Thanks to Roger's answer below. It appears the Boss API has been shut down (at least in version 1).

I'm looking for an LSI search script asap. Anyone for hire to build one, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, version 1 of BOSS was disabled on July 20th, replaced by version 2, which is for-pay only:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ysearchboss/message/3570

Comment: Adding a bit of text to prevent needless link clicking would make this answer a bit worthier.

Comment: Well, that explains it. Thanks Roger! Anyone wants to build an LSI search script for a fee, let me know. I need one asap!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.